# How to deploy a SpringBoot REST Application to Google App Engine?

Tags: google-app-engine, spring-boot, google-cloud-platform

**Tried**

Subscribed trial for GoogleAppEngine.

```
1. INSTALLED GOOGLE APP ENGINE SDK
2. Downloaded the sample Java started code and deployed it. Working fine.
3. Used $appcfg.sh -A <appname> update target/appengine-try-java-1.0 to deploy
4. In this case, its a folder with all the webapp related stuffs
```

**Question**

In my case, I have a spring boot application which generates a jar file. It runs with a embedded container and I believe Google may have an alternate to deploy using Docker or some other way. But how?

There is no pointer or any details on how to run this in Google managed platform as far as I searched.

Any help or reference to documentation!! Alternates??

Comment: You can generate a WAR file for your Spring Boot application.  Just check the official documentation on how to do that with Maven or Gradle, depending on which of those you are using.

Comment: @manish Any +s -s to wrap it as a webapp? Can you point me to official documentation. appcfg.sh only accepts war directories, I can simply maven package it as a war and it will give me a folder with webapp. But I wanted to know whether Google provides any official recommendation.

Comment: Using JAR v/s WAR makes no difference to the application at runtime.  The fat JAR produced by default is just for convenience.  See [How to create a deployable WAR file](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#howto-create-a-deployable-war-file).  If you use Maven, you can add the AppEngine Maven plugin to your POM file and then run `mvn appengine:update` to push the WAR to AppEngine.  Please be warned that AppEngine does not support all Java EE features so you will have to work through issues on your own if you run into any.

Comment: +1 for [appengine-maven-plugin](https://code.google.com/p/appengine-maven-plugin/) suggestion. I just have few REST endpoints declared for my mobile app, what sort of features support would I be missing?

Comment: [This page](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/) has all the details.

Comment: @raksja How did you solve it?

Answer (score 10):

You can now use **Google App Engine Java Flexible Environment** - **Java 8 Runtime**:

https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/java/dev-java-only

It is Docker based

**UPDATE:**

You can now use Java 8 in **App Engine Standard Environment**:

- Tutorial:
  https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/cloud-app-engine-springboot/index.html
- Example:
  https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/getting-started-java/tree/master/appengine-standard-java8/springboot-appengine-standard
- Blog post:
  https://cloudplatform.googleblog.com/2017/09/Java-8-on-App-Engine-Standard-environment-is-now-generally-available.html

Comment: looks promising.. lets try

Comment: It's also in beta (as of Nov 2016).  You've been warned.

Comment: The App Engine flexible environment is generally available (GA) since March 9, 2017. You can run Node.js, Ruby, Python, Java, and Go applications with a 99.95% SLA. - https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/java/release-notes

Comment: Google App Engine is tied to the Servlet 2.5 API, so you can’t deploy a Spring boot Application because it uses the Servlet 3.0. How we can solve this problem in App Engine Flexible ?

Comment: @Majico : you can use The Java 8 Runtime with App Engine Flexible environment and pack your Spring Boot in Docker: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/java/dev-java-only

Comment: @Danail, Is there a way to run Spring Boot Jars on App Engine standard?

Comment: @Anoop Hallimala yes, please check the docs https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/ and https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/getting-started-java/tree/master/appengine-standard-java8/springboot-appengine-standard

Answer (score 7):

Google App Engine still uses Servlet 2.5 that is below the requirements of Spring Boot (i.e. Servlet 3.0).

There is a way to workaround that, check [the documentation for more details](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#cloud-deployment-gae)

Answer (score 3):

Spring Boot requires Servlet 3.0 which GAE does not have. WorkAround is to have a "`spring-boot-legacy`" dependency. You can check further how to implement: https://github.com/scratches/spring-boot-sample-gae